# How can I format a dynamic output to create a table in a printf

Tags: c, format, printf

I have this big printf, tha fills with a file.

```
 printf("\n%s \t\t%s \t\t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n", instante, territorio, blancos, nulos, subscritos,elegidos,porcentaje, validos, votos, hondt, estimados);
```

The thing is that I need to format the alignment stdout because now is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify how many characters should be used and rest would be filled with spaces, `%20s` would give you 20 characters for instance, or `%-20s` if you want padding on the right side.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *items[] = { "First", "Second one", "Third" };
    char *clients[] = { "Jon Doe", "Carol Anne", "Roscoe Williams" };

    printf("%-20s\t%-20s\n", "Item", "Client");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%-20s\t%-20s\n", items[i], clients[i]);
}
```

Comment: It works very well but it's not 100% dynamic. How use a variable to define the number of characters should be used and rest would be filled with spaces ?

Comment: `int l = 23;` is number of characters you want. Then you have your format `char fmt[10];`, adjust the size as needed. You create a format string like that `sprintf(fmt, "%%-%ds", l);` and use it like `printf(fmt, someString);`.

For the example above it would be:
`char fmt[15];
sprintf(fmt, "%%-%ds\t%%-%ds\n", l, l);
printf(fmt, items[i], clients[i]);`

Comment: Of course you should use snprintf to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

printf supports padding. You should pad left or right every column to a fixed size

```
print("%-10s", 'test')
```